# Python Magic (smart, dual-mode) SSL Socket?

Tags: python, ssl

I'm writing an application that will make use of Python's HTTPServer and BaseHTTPRequest. At some point I figured that due to the sensitive nature of the data user might want to send, an implementation of SOCKS would be useful. The problem is - the application is planned to run on a non-standard port and thus it would be useful if it could talk to both plaintext and SSL connections. I've found [there](http://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/) a way to make HTTPServer use SSL:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='path/to/localhost.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Is there a way to create a socket class that would handle both SSL and plaintext connections? A neat way to detect SSL (i.e. some magic bytes)? The alternative would be to allocate two ports, but that's way less cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've investigated the problem a little bit. 
It's easy to make a socket behave like two different servers (depending on the type of data received). What's bad here is that python's _ssl library reads directly from socket._socket, which is a native python object and therefore can't be hooked normally.

One way is to write a C module that will hook native python socket. 
Another solution is to have 1 frontend and 2 backends (https and http). Frontend listens on 4443 and decides whether it should commutate connection with https backend or http backend. You can add the same handlers to the both servers and they'll behave in the same way. Another problem is that on backend we don't know the ip of the client, but there are workarounds (Like the dict {(Frontend to backend source port number): Client IP} that frontend will be keeping and backends will be looking at).

Comparing with the C solution, the second looks quite dirty, but here it is.

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl
import socket
import select
import threading

FRONTEND_PORT = 4443
BACKEND_PORT_SSL = 44431
BACKEND_PORT_HTTP = 44432
HOST = 'localhost'

httpd_ssl = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST, BACKEND_PORT_SSL), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd_ssl.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd_ssl.socket, certfile='key.pem', server_side=True)

httpd_direct = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST, BACKEND_PORT_HTTP), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

def serve_forever(http_server):
    http_server.serve_forever()

def categorize(sock, addr):
    data = sock.recv(1)
    if data == '\x16':
        port = BACKEND_PORT_SSL
    else:
        port = BACKEND_PORT_HTTP
    other_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    other_sock.connect((HOST, port))
    other_sock.send(data)
    inp = [sock, other_sock]
    select_timeout = 1.0
    try:
        while 1:
            r,w,x = select.select(inp,[],[],select_timeout)
            if not r:
                continue
            for s in r:
                o_s = inp[1] if inp[0]==s else inp[0]
                buf = s.recv(4096)
                if not buf:
                    raise socket.error
                o_s.send(buf)
    except socket.error:
        pass
    finally:
        for s in inp:
            s.close()

threading.Thread(target=serve_forever, args=(httpd_ssl,)).start()
threading.Thread(target=serve_forever, args=(httpd_direct,)).start()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((HOST, FRONTEND_PORT))
sock.listen(10)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=categorize, args=(conn, addr)).start()
```

Comment: And about the first idea. It's possible to hook sock_recv(PySocketSockObject *s, PyObject *args). But this will affect all the sockets. So we have to find a good way to distinguish hooked and not hooked sockets. e.g. use a global dictionary, but a dict lookup on every recv would cost quite a lot, I wonder if we can store at least a bit in PySocketSockObject structure. So the first solution is even more dirtier.

Comment: Hm, why isn't it possible to create a class that contains a _sock object acting like a proxy between the real _sock and the wrapped one?

Comment: Well, I might be wrong, but _sock.recv isn't a method like foo.bar(), it is a hardcoded function in socketmodule.c `{"recv", (PyCFunction)sock_recv, METH_VARARGS, recv_doc}` in array `PyMethodDef sock_methods[]`, and when you call `my_sock._sock.recv`, a C function `sock_recv` is called with first argument being a `PySocketSockObject *` which points to `my_sock._sock`. So the only solution is to write a module in C, which will replace `sock_recv` with our C function. But if we do this, the problem mentioned in my prev comment appear.

Comment: So, I meant that you can't replace socket._socket.recv method for one object, like you can do with usual objects because socket._socket is written in C, therefore replaced will take place for all the sockets in your program.

Comment: Yeah, but it's called from within Python code. You can easily do:

class A: pass; httpd.socket._socket = A()

Comment: Oh, yes, of course you can do that trick for pure python modules but you won't be able to hook openssl because python ssl.c module just does `SSL_set_fd(self->ssl, Sock->sock_fd); /* Set the socket for SSL */` and then that fd is handled by openssl library which doesn't know anything about your fake_socket and just does write and read on system file descriptor.

Comment: ...So one would have to reimplement quite a lot of low-level stuff for that to work. That sucks. Thanks for trying then! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with a helper class that peeks into the received data upon `accept()`, and then returns either a wrapped or the naked socket:

```
class SmartServerSocket:
    def __init__( self, sock ):
        self.sock = sock
        # delegate methods as needed
        _delegate_methods = [ "fileno" ]
        for method in _delegate_methods:
            setattr( self, method, getattr( sock, method ) )
    def accept( self ):
        (conn, addr) = self.sock.accept()
        if conn.recv( 1, socket.MSG_PEEK ) == "\x16":
            return (ssl.wrap_socket( conn, certfile='path/to/localhost.pem', server_side=True ), addr)
        else:
            return (conn, addr)

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer( ('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler )
httpd.socket = SmartServerSocket( httpd.socket )
httpd.serve_forever()
```

If you like, you can give the server object to the `SmartServerSocket` constructor and have `accept()` set a special member variable there to the detected protocol, so you can examine this in the `RequestHandler` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [there acutally is](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt).

But I don't know of any client or server that implements STARTLS for HTTP. It's commonly used for IMAP and SMTP, but for HTTP unfortunately there don't seem to be any implementations, it's still common practice to serve HTTP on a different port then HTTPS.

Comment: I need a server-side solution.

Comment: There isn't any I'm aware of. By the way, you probably don't really mean [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) but SSL.